# Why is Ruby's Array#shift used in this task?

Tags: ruby

I'm going through this annoying tutorial on Rubymonk and it asks me to do the following:

*Write for me three methods - calculate, add and subtract. The tests should all pass. Take a look at the hint if you have trouble! And as a little extra hint: remember that you can use something.is_a?(Hash) or another_thing.is_a?(String) to check an object's type.*

I couldn't even understand what they ask me to do, so I just decided to see the solution and and work my way into a decent understanding of the task.

Here is the solution:

```
def add(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }  
end

def subtract(*numbers)
  current_result = numbers.shift
  numbers.inject(current_result) { |current_result, number| current_result - number }  
end

def calculate(*arguments)
  # if the last argument is a Hash, extract it 
  # otherwise create an empty Hash
  options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
  options[:add] = true if options.empty?
  return add(*arguments) if options[:add]
  return subtract(*arguments) if options[:subtract]
end
```

I don't understand many things, but the one thing that baffles me is the shift method: current_result = numbers.shift. Why is it there? I mean, I understand what it does, but what's its job in this particular piece of code?

Btw, if someone goes to the trouble to break this code down for me I would be endlessly and eternally thankful.

The task is at the bottom of the following page:
https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/19-ruby-methods/lessons/69-new-lesson#solution3899

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**add(*numbers)**

Let's start by invoking:

```
def add(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }  
end
```

like this:

```
add(1,2,3)    #=> 6
```

or like this:

```
add(*[1,2,3]) #=> 6
```

The two are equivalent. The latter shows you what the operator "splat" does.

This results in:

```
numbers      #=> [1,2,3]
```

so Ruby sends [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (aka `reduce`) to `numbers`:

```
[1,2,3].inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }
```

`inject` first initializes the "memo" `sum` to `inject`'s argument (if, as here, it has one) and then passes the first element of the "receiver" `[1,2,3]` into the block and assigns it to the block variable `number`:

```
sum          #=> 0
number       #=> 1
```

Ruby then computes:

```
sum + number #=> 0 + 1 => 1
```

which becomes the new value of the memo. Next, `inject` passes `2` into the block and computes:

```
sum          #=> 1
number       #=> 2
sum + number #=> 3
```

so (the memo) `sum` is now `3`.

Lastly,

```
sum          #=> 3
number       #=> 3
sum + number #=> 6
```

As all elements of the receiver have been passed into the block, `inject` returns the value of the memo:

```
sum          #=> 6
```

If you examine the doc for `inject` you'll see that if the method has no argument Ruby assigns the first element of the receiver (here `1`) to the memo (`sum`) and then carries on as above starting with the second element of the receiver (`2`). As expected, this produces the same answer:

```
def add(*numbers)
  numbers.inject { |sum, number| sum + number }  
end

add(1,2,3) #=> 6
```

So why include the argument zero? Often we will want `add()` (i.e., `add(*[]))` to return zero. I will leave it to you to investigate what happens here with each of the two forms of `inject`. What conclusion can you draw?

As @Stefan points out in his answer, you can simply this to:

```
def add(*numbers)
  numbers.inject :+
end
```

which is how you'd normally see it written.

If, however, `numbers` may be an empty array, you'd want to provide an initial value of zero for the memo:

```
def add(*numbers)
  numbers.inject 0, :+
end

add(*[]) #=> 0
```

**subtract(*numbers)**

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  current_result = numbers.shift
  numbers.inject(current_result) { |current_result, number|
    current_result - number }  
end
```

This is similar to the method `add`, with a small twist. We need the first value of the memo (here `current_result`) to be the first element of the receiver. There are two ways we could do that.

The first way is like this:

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers[1..-1].inject(numbers.first) { |current_result, number|
    current_result - number }  
end

numbers = [6,2,3]    
subtract(*numbers) #=> 1
```

Let

```
first_number = numbers.first   #=> 6
all_but_first = numbers[1..-1] #=> [2,3]
```

then:

```
numbers[1..-1].inject(numbers.first) { ... }
```

is:

```
all_but_first.inject(first_number) { ... }
  #=> [2,3].inject(6) { ... }
```

Instead, the author chose to write:

```
first_number = numbers.shift   #=> 6
numbers                        #=> [2,3]

numbers.inject(first_number) { ... }
  #=> [2,3].inject(6) { ... }
```

which may be a bit niftier, but the choice is yours.

The second way is to use `inject` without an argument:

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers.inject { |current_result, number| current_result - number }  
end

numbers = [6,2,3]    
subtract(*numbers) #=> 1
```

You can see why this works by reviewing the doc for `inject`.

Moreover, similar to `:add`, you can write:

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers.inject :-  
end
```

Lastly, `subtract` requires `numbers` to have at least one element, so we might write:

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  raise ArgumentError, "argument cannot be an empty array" if numbers.empty?
  numbers.inject :-  
end
```

**calculate(*arguments)**

We see that `calculate` expects to be invoked in one of the following ways:

```
calculate(6,2,3,{ :add=>true })      #=> 11 
calculate(6,2,3,{ :add=>7 })         #=> 11  
calculate(6,2,3,{ :subtract=>true }) #=> 1 
calculate(6,2,3,{ :subtract=>7 })    #=> 1 
calculate(6,2,3)                     #=> 11
```

If the hash has a key `:add` with a "truthy" value (anything other than `false` or `nil`, we are to add; if the hash has a key `:subtract` with a "truthy" value (anything other than `false` or `nil`, we are to subtract. If the last element is not a hash (`calculate(6,2,3)`), `add` is assumed.

Note:

```
calculate(6,2,3,{ :add=>false })     #=> nil
calculate(6,2,3,{ :subtract=>nil })  #=> nil
```

Let's write the method like this:

```
def calculate(*arguments)
  options =
  if arguments.last.is_a?(Hash) # or if arguments.last.class==Hash 
    arguments.pop
  else
    {}
  end 

  if (options.empty? || options[:add])
    add *arguments
  elsif options[:subtract]
    subtract *arguments
  else
    nil
  end
end

calculate(6,2,3,{ :add=>true })      #=> 11 
calculate(6,2,3,{ :add=>7 })         #=> 11  
calculate(6,2,3,{ :subtract=>true }) #=> 1 
calculate(6,2,3,{ :subtract=>7 })    #=> 1 
calculate(6,2,3)                     #=> 11 
calculate(6,2,3,{ :add=>false })     #=> nil
calculate(6,2,3,{ :subtract=>nil })  #=> nil
```

Note the `return` keyword is not needed (nor is it needed in the original code). It seems very odd that a hash would be used to signify the type of operation to be performed. It would make more sense to invoke the method:

```
calculate(6,2,3,:add)                #=> 11 
calculate(6,2,3)                     #=> 11 
calculate(6,2,3,:subtract)           #=> 1
```

We can implement that as follows:

```
def calculate(*arguments)
  operation =
  case arguments.last
  when :add
    arguments.pop
    :add
  when :subtract
    arguments.pop
    :subtract
  else
    :add
  end

  case operation
  when :add
    add *arguments
  else
    subtract *arguments
  end
end
```

Better:

```
def calculate(*arguments, op=:add)
  case op
  when :subtract
    subtract *arguments
  else
    add *arguments
  end
end

calculate(6,2,3,:add)                #=> 11 
calculate(6,2,3)                     #=> 11 
calculate(6,2,3,:subtract)           #=> 1
```

I am overwhelmed by your offer to be "endlessly and eternally thankful", but if you appreciate my efforts for a few minutes, that is sufficient.

Comment: Jeez, I guessed it was you, after I scrolled past two screens of the answer :)

Comment: Wow. Every time a question popped up in my head you answered it in the next line. Thank you Sir, your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Since its `calculate(*arguments)`, we know there are a variable number of arguments, From the code we see that the last argument may be a hash. If it is a hash, it tells us whether we should add or subtract the preceding arguments; if it's not a hash we are to add all the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

> `current_result = numbers.shift`. Why is it there? I mean, I understand what it does, but what's its job in this particular piece of code?

The line removes the first element from the `numbers` array and assigns it to `current_result`. Afterwards, `current_result - number` is calculated for each `number` in the remaining `numbers` array.

Example with logging:

```
numbers = [20, 3, 2]
current_result = numbers.shift

current_result #=> 20
numbers        #=> [3, 2]

numbers.inject(current_result) do |current_result, number|
  (current_result - number).tap do |result|
    puts "#{current_result} - #{number} = #{result}"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
20 - 3 = 17
17 - 2 = 15
```

`15` would be the method's return value.

However, removing the first element is not necessary; [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) does this by default:

> If you do not explicitly specify an *initial* value for *memo*, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of *memo*.

Thus, the `subtract` method can be simplified:

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers.inject { |current_result, number| current_result - number }  
end

subtract(20, 3, 2) #=> 15
```

You can also provide a method symbol:

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(:-)
end
```

Same works for `add`:

```
def add(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(:+)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that `shift` is completely unnecessary in this this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation of `subtract` method**

Lets say your input was [2,3,4,5].

In your mind, you can think that you need a program which does this

```
result = 2 # This is first element of array
result = result - 3  # This is second element of array
result = result - 4  # This is third element of array
result = result - 5  # This is fourth element of array
```

So that finally, you end up with

```
result = -10
```

`shift` allows you to take the first element from the array, so that you can use `inject` on remaining elements with first element shifted of array acting as `accumulator` value.

The above explanation will make sense if you are aware of how [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method [works](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html).

Same approach could have been taken for `add` method as well.

```
def add(*numbers)
  current_result = numbers.shift
  numbers.inject(current_result) { |current_result, number| current_result + number }  
end
```

However, the authors of the `add` code used the more orthodox version of `inject` in their implementation as adding `0` to another number will not have any impact.

If authors used their `add` method and replaced `+` with `-`, they would have ended up with

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers.inject(0) { |result, number| result - number }  
end
```

However, `subtract([2,3,4,5])` would have provided output of `-14` (`0-2-3-4-5 = -14`) instead of `-10` (`2-3-4-5 = -10`).

To fix the above code, one will have to get rid of default parameter `0` in both `add` and `subtract`, and write something like below

```
def subtract(*numbers)
  numbers.inject { |result, number| result - number }  
end

def add(*numbers)
  numbers.inject { |result, number| result + number }  
end
```

We will now get right result of `-10` for `subtract([2,3,4,5])`

The above code works because as documented [here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html) (and also expressed in other answers)

> The argument to inject is actually optional. If a default value is not
>   passed in as an argument, the first time the block executes, the first
>   argument will be set to the first element of the enumerable and the
>   second argument will be set to the second element of the enumerable.

In summary, authors of [Rubymonk](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/19-ruby-methods/lessons/69-new-lesson#solution3899) could have avoided the confusion, or may be they were trying to teach the reader one more Ruby trick by using `shift`

**Explanation of `calculate` method**

An easy to understand version of `calculate` can be something like below:

```
def calculate(*arguments, options)
  return add(*arguments) if options[:add]
  return subtract(*arguments) if options[:subtract]
end

p calculate(1,2,3,4,{add: true}) # Adds the numbers, outputs 10
p calculate(1,2,3,4,{subtract: true}) # Subtracts the numbers, outputs -8
```

Ruby will assign last parameter of function call to `options` and rest of elements as an array to `arguments`.  If we called `calculate` with only one parameter, that will be the value of `options`.

```
p calculate({add: true})  # Outputs 0
p calculate(1) # Will return error as 1 is not a Hash and can't be assigned to 'options'
```

Author of code wanted to make `options` an optional argument, so that below code worked as well.

```
p calculate(1,2,3,4) # Assume add, and output 10
```

That will require a change in the simpler version of `calculate` such that instead of explicitly declaring `options` as the argument to `calculate`, we can use the last element of `arguments` array as `options` if it is of type `Hash`.  We will thus end up implementing the `calculate` as shown on the [Rubymonk](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/19-ruby-methods/lessons/69-new-lesson#solution3899).

Comment: while you are correct shift has no useful purpose here since `inject` will automatically use the first argument as the initial memo value unless one is given so in this case `numbers.inject(:-)` would have the same impact with or without the shift.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for the tips.  My original goal of this answer was to  answer the question in OP as author sought explanation for a specific piece of code